# How to share useRef globally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use a `useRef` between 2 components which are not directly linked.

How?

Since useRef is a hook, I cant just add this to some file and share it.

```
export const someRef = React.useRef(); // not possible, it needs to be inside a jsx component
```

I am trying to find a way to use it globally similar to how this would have been possible if this was state.

I'd have just used existing `Redux` implementation or `context` if this was state.

Please advice how to do the same for `useRef`. I don't own Compo2 component below thus I need to stick with a ref here.

P.S: I could achieve this with some prop drilling going 6 levels down.. Trying not to do that.

```
// place reference on this component
export const Compo1 = () => {
  return (
    <div ref={someRef}>
      text 1
    </div>
  );
};


// same  someRef reference passed as a prop here from some other component which doesn't talk to Compo1. 
export const Compo2 = ({
  someRef,  
}) => {
  // Do something with the reference value
  return (
    <div>
      text 2
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: If you don't "own" component 2 then you'll not be able to write code to "do something with the ref", surely?

Comment: @Andy The logic to do something with the ref already exists in that component 2.

Comment: And then there was [createRef()](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new global variable, for example:

```js
export const inputRef = { current: null };

function Input() {
  return (
    <label>
      <input type="text" ref={inputRef} placeholder="Type something" />
    </label>
  );
}
export default Input;
```

And then you can use it like you normally would, by importing.o

```js
import Input, { inputRef } from "./Input";

function Container({ children }) {
  function handleClick() {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  }

  return (
    <div
      onClick={handleClick}
      style={{
        padding: 16,
        backgroundColor: "yellow",
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Input />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

See here [a live version](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-keller-8si8i6)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to object refs (an object with `current` prop), refs also accept functions ([ref callback functions](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#ref-callback)). A function ref (like `setRef`) is passed the ref to the element when called.

Instead of `useRef`, you can use `useState` instead, get the ref using the setter function, and set it as the state. You can then pass the state to another component.

You can use a parent component in this way, or use context.

For example:

```
// place reference on this component
export const Compo1 = ({ setRef }) => {
  return (
    <div ref={setRef}>
      text 1
    </div>
  );
};


// same  someRef reference passed as a prop here from some other component which doesn't talk to Compo1. 
export const Compo2 = ({ someRef }) => {
  // Do something with the reference value
  return (
    <div>
      text 2
    </div>
  );
};

const Parent = () => {
  const [ref, setRef] = useState();

  return (
    <>
      <Compo1 setRef={setRef} />
      <Compo2 someRef={ref} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To create ref in another file and use it in two different components which are not linked with each other you can use `createRef`

**App.js**

```
import { refs } from "./constant";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div ref={refs} className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Comp1.js**

```
import { refs } from "./constant";

export default function Comp1() {
  return <button onClick={() => console.log(refs)}>button</button>;
}
```

**constant.js**

```
import React from "react";

export const refs = React.createRef();
```

**index.js**

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";
import Comp1 from "./Comp1";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
    <Comp1 />
  </StrictMode>
);
```